# Is it possible to iterate LinkedHashMap in both the ways as it is implemented with help of Doubly Linked List?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Is it possible to iterate LinkedHashMap in both the ways as it is implemented with help of Doubly Linked List ?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. The `LinkedHashMap` itself doesn't even provide a way to get an iterator (unless you count `forEach()`), so you'd need to iterate either the `keySet()`, `entrySet()` or `values()`. They only provide a regular forward-only `Iterator`.

It would be possible to create a `List` out of the `entrySet()`. It would keep the order and you could then iterate it as you wish, but you do incur the cost of creating the `List`.

Comment: Using reflection it would be possible though, just as note.

Comment: @Zabuza I *usually* don't consider reflection, JNI or `Unsafe` in my answers. Pretty much *anything* is possible if you really want it, but that's not really something you'd do in a professional software engineering situation.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. But I wanted to mention it for OP. Maybe, for whatever reason, it is an option for him.

Comment: @Zabuza yet you commented it on my answer. I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

### Design

From a designers point of view, technically the current implementation of `LinkedHashMap` would be able to do so.

However they don't provide access to this. That also allows the developer to change the internal implementation someday. If they would provide both iteration directions, they would need to **stick** to that for the future in order to ensure **backwards compatibility**.

By the documentation, the only benefit of a `LinkedHashMap` should be to ensure **iteration in insertion order**, nothing more. So it only provides stuff needed for exactly that goal.

---

### Manual (extra cost)

Without deploying reflection you won't be able to access the internal `LinkedList` and won't be able to iterate in both directions.

You can of course manually create a `LinkedList` on your own and use that for iteration in both directions:

```
LinkedHashMap<K, V> map = ...

LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
Iterator<Entry<K, V>> descIter = entries.descendingIterator();

while (descIter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<K, V> entry = descIter.next();
    ...
}
```

---

### Reflection (no extra cost but discouraged)

Using **reflection** you can however access the internal `LinkedList`, note that this is **strongly discouraged** in general. It is not that easy since the linked list is implemented manually, therefore refer to [an implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java) like from *OpenJDK version 8u40-b25*.

First we need to access the `tail` element of `LinkedHashMap`:

```
transient LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> tail;
```

Therefore we need to make it public first and then retrieve the value:

```
Class<?> c = map.getClass();
Field tailField = c.getDeclaredField("tail");
tailField.setAccessible(true);
Object tailValue = tailField.get(map);
Entry<K, V> tail = (Entry<K, V>) tailValue;
```

Now you can start iterating using the tail, following the `before` field of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`:

```
Entry<K,V> before, after;
```

Iteration then looks like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<K, V> map = ...

// Get tail as seen before
Entry<K, V> tail = ...

// Preparation for accessing "before" element
Class<?> c = tail.getClass();
Field beforeField = c.getDeclaredField("before");
beforeField.setAccessible(true);

Entry<K, V> entry = tail;
while (entry != null) {
    // Do something with entry
    ...

    // Get next element
    Object beforeValue = beforeField.get(entry);
    entry = (Entry<K, V>) beforeValue;
}
```

Be aware that by this you break the intended design of the class. You should be aware of why reflection is **discouraged** in general. Your code will break if the designers change the implementation of the class in the future.